# Restricted isometry property (RIP) constant

Tags: matrices

Firstly, the definition of RIP constant is given as

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an $m\times p$ matrix and let $1 \leq s \leq p$ be an integer. Suppose that there exists a constant $\delta _{s}\in (0,1)$ such that  every $s$-sparse vector $\mathbf{v}$ satisfies

\begin{align}
    (1-\delta _{s})||\mathbf{v}||_2^2 \leq ||\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}||_2^2 \leq (1+\delta _{s})||\mathbf{v}||_2^2
\end{align}

Then, the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is said to satisfy the $s$-restricted isometry property with restricted isometry constant $\delta_s$.

My question: Does the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ need to be column normalized? If not column normalized, the eigen values of random generated $\mathbf{A}^H\mathbf{A}$ could be very large. For example, when the eigenvalues are $[5 \;4.9 \;4.8\; 4.7]$, the columns of matrix $\mathbf{A}$ are actually quasi-orthognal. However, it does not satisfy the RIP property defined above.

I've searched over many literatures, but almost all of the highly cited work neglect the column normalization.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Elad's book, where the columns need to be $l_{2}$ normalised (chapter 5 page 86).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. This post explains how to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).  The lingua franca for formulation is [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).